# Proving relationship between Euler's totient function and Mobius function

Tags: abstract-algebra, mobius-inversion

I'm trying to prove that 
$$\phi(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\phi(d)$$

My attempt is the following:

Mobius inversion formula tells us that, since 
$$n=\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)$$

then 
$$\phi(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\frac{n}{d}$$

so 
$$\phi(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\sum_{d'|(n/d)}\phi\left({d'}\right)$$
but I don't know how to procceed. Any hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about using induction on the number of prime factors of n.

Comment: Once you know $\phi(n)$ is multiplicative then so is $\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\phi(d)$ so it suffices to check $\phi(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\phi(d)$ for $n = p^k$

Answer (score 2):

It occurs to me that, as written, this is false.
$$\phi(9)=6\ne -1 = 0-2+1 = \mu(9)\phi(9) + \mu(3)\phi(3) + \mu(1)\phi(1)$$